# Didn't find any option for csharp_outer_classname in protocol buffers with C#. Is there any other way I can setup outer classname in proto file?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

Is there any option for csharp_outer_classname in protocol buffers with C#?
I am using "option java_outer_classname" for java based setup. But I didn't find this kind of outer class declaration for the C#.

Can anyone help me to get any other solution to work around it?

Thanks!